# Real time refresh multiple rooms (PHP & AJAX)

Tags: php, ajax, sockets, comet, live

I have over 200 rooms where people can visit at my website only to WATCH the messages posted(they can't talk or write or whatever, just see)  through viewroom.php?id=xx

otherhand i have people with a mobile app to send messages (only send) to a specific room, the app call a file sendmes.php?room=xx in my server , at this point i have all working but without live refresh , i wonder the best system and also as light server load as posible to send through sendmes.php to viewroom.php without heavy lops and that

I tried with Ajax and long timeouts, but that way force me to do loops to mysql or files and in my opinion  it's a hight server load way

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend changing the back-end architecture of your system.

Look into [Node.js](http://www.nodejs.org/) with [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/).  It is a simple wrapper for Web Sockets (as well as [long-polling AJAX if the browser support isn't there](http://socket.io/#browser-support)) that makes this whole process easy.  Have your clients send all of their messages to your Node instance, and then have  your Node application write to your database for archival purposes.

Comment: Thanks guys, i will give a try to each system, a bit hard to me though

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to work with messages, I suggest using an established messaging system - like [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/), for example (we have actually used it with great success in one of our projects) - instead of writing your own logic for storing and queuing them.

This way the only thing you'll need to write is a lightweight 'server push' script - it'll query the Messaging Subsystem for the incoming messages, and route them to specific rooms/users.